# RODBC sqlSave crashes R front end

Tags: r, ms-access, crash, rodbc

i am trying to write to an msaccess database using sqlSave from the RODBC package.  i have no problems opening a connection to the database.  i am able to read from tables.  i can even make certain simple updates using sqlSave, but for the following table and the following update the R front end crashes.  This happens both when running this from Rscript with real calculated data and from Rstudio when I run the following commands.  i am running R 3.1 in 32 bit mode (for compatibility with access).

i have created a channel 'ch' and i am intending to write to a table called 'Test_Table' in a database called 'data.mdb'

```
test <- c(1,"Fixed","Upward","Gas", "2014-07-31",14,0.99)

test.df <- as.data.frame(t(test))

names(test.df) <- c("ID","Contract_Type","Direction", "Name_Of_Underlying","Data_Date","Months_To_Maturity","Absolute_Price_Move")

types <- c("integer","varchar","varchar","varchar","datetime","integer","double")
names(types) <- names(test.df)

sqlSave(ch, dat = test.df, tablename = "Test_Table",varTypes = types, append = T, verbose = T,safer = T)
```

I've also tried this with safer = F.

When I run this in RStudio I get the 'bomb' sign and am asked to start a new session.  When I run via Rscript, the command line output indicates that all the correct bindings are occurring and that the parameters are correct.  Then a window pops up to say that R for Windows front-end has stopped working and nothing has been written to the database.

Any thoughts are welcomed.

Comment: when i debug Rscript in Visual Studio, i get the following error: Unhandled exception at 0x6C72A6E4 (R.dll) in Rscript.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: just a little more info, if i remove the datetime field this save works.  it also crashes when i convert the datetime string to POSIX.

Comment: i got this to work using an INSERT INTO statement and sqlQuery, but i would still really like to know how to make sqlSave do the trick.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, it crashes the R console as well

Answer (score 13):

I had similar problem when I was trying to append data to existing table in MS SQL using sqlSave(). It has started to work when I added argument rownames=FALSE into sqlSave. In the RODBC package description there is:

rownames: If logical, save the row names as the first column rownames in the table?

The default value is TRUE, so I guess that RStudio crashed because I had no column for row names in table in database.

Comment: This didn't work for me, and surely even if it did it's an R bug?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen a few times when appending rows. In my cases, having extra columns in the dataframe seemed to be the issue. when I removed the columns from the dataframe that were not in the table, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and I added rownames = F and fast = F and it worked. I added both of these in the same edit so I'm not sure which caused the script to work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35648193)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).